# (Powershell) Remove spaces in output and print output to file

Tags: powershell

```
$word = Get-Content C:\Users\Documents\words.txt    
    
 for ($i = 0; $i -lt $word.Count; $i++){
       Write-Host "How do I remove this >"$word.GetValue($i)"< space in between variable"
        }
```


The output is like this:

```
How do I remove this >test1< space before and after the arrow
How do I remove this >test2< space before and after the arrow
How do I remove this >test3< space before and after the arrow
How do I remove this >test4< space before and after the arrow
How do I remove this >test5< space before and after the arrow
How do I remove this >test6< space before and after the arrow
How do I remove this >test7< space before and after the arrow
```

Also, how do I save output this to a file.
I have tried using this

```
for ($i = 0; $i -lt $word.Count; $i++){
          $line1 = Write-Host ("How do I remove this >" + $word.GetValue($i) + "< space in between variable")
          $line1 >> C:\Users\Documents\blip.txt
            }
```

Comment: I'm sure you can accomplish this with RegEx but, since you're using this in a loop use `.Trim()` method. You also could use a regular `foreach` loop instead. Much friendlier to use.  `foreach ($var in $word.Trim())`

Comment: The spaces are a consequence of how `Write-Host` processes the different values it is given. In your example you are actually giving `Write-Host` 3 strings. "How do I remove this >", the word and "< space in between variable". Write-Host takes the 3 parts and joins them into one string using spaces. Join the 3 parts yourself into 1 string using + and surround with parentheses to avoid Write-Hosts behavior `Write-Host ("How do I remove this >" + $word.GetValue($i).Trim() + "< space in between variable")`

Comment: `(Get-Content C:\Users\Documents\words.txt).Trim()` should work too

Comment: @AbrahamZinala I have tried the those options before. But thanks for the share too!

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for the explanation and help rendered. It works!

Comment: How do you save the output to a file? i added double >> to ensure it doesnt overwrite the contents in file written previously

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you're not seeing `blip.txt` file being populated is because you're using `Write-Host`, which as it's name implies, it's meant exclusively for console output. By default it's output can't be captured unless [redirected (`6>&1`)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-7.2):

```sh
# `Hello` is outputted to the console and `$null` is assigned to `$test`
$test = Write-Host 'Hello'
$test # => $null

# `Hello` is redirected to the success stream and assigned to `$test`
$test = Write-Host 'Hello' 6>&1
$test # => Hello
```

The code could be simplified to this:

```sh
Get-Content C:\Users\Documents\words.txt | ForEach-Object {
    "How do I remove this${_}space before and after the arrow"
} | Set-Content C:\Users\Documents\blip.txt
```

If you really need to `.Trim()` each line of your input file, then you can change the above for:

```sh
"How do I remove this$($_.Trim())space before and after the arrow"
```

Comment: I have written another line of code below. This code overwritten the output in blip.txt. Is there any way to not overwrite and instead add-on the words in blip.txt 

Get-Content C:\Users\Documents\words.txt | ForEach-Object {
    "test1 ${_}"
} | Set-Content C:\Users\Documents\blip.txt

Comment: @Nizuru if you want to "append" to an existing file your can use `Out-File /path/to/output.ext -Append` instead of `Set-Content`